# Грамотное распределение данных по таблицам php

Tags: phpmyadmin, хранение-данных

Пишу свой собственный проект вот уже как месяц. Добрался до системы комментариев на сайте.  Возник такой вопрос: стоит ли собирать все комментарии на сайте в одну таблицу и относящиеся к записям на странице и к записям к группе.
 В первом случае:
Различать id пользователя и группы можно прибавлением опознавательных знаков вначале. 
Во втором случае: 
Создать две таблицы. Одна относится к комментированию в группах, вторая к комментированию на странице. 
Сайт планирую со средней нагрузкой. Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 1):

> стоит ли собирать все комментарии на сайте в одну таблицу и относящиеся к записям на странице и к записям к группе

Да, стоит собирать в одну таблицу, чтобы избежать избыточности в схеме данных. У вас комментарии будут отличаться лишь размещением (на странице или в группе), поэтому можно сделать одну таблицу с доп.признаком.

> Сайт планирую со средней нагрузкой

Какую бы нагрузку Вы ни "планировали", в реальности она будет совсем другой. Лучше смотреть на нагрузочный профиль проекта уже после запуска, чтобы избежать излишней предварительной оптимизации. Например, вы сейчас оптимизируете хранение комментариев, а на деле окажется, что комментариев оставляют мало (вместо этого делятся страницей в соцсетях и уже там комментируют).